# Python 3 - Object Oriented Programming - Classes & Functions

Tags: python-3.x

I have been studying Python 3 for a few months now and have just begun looking at Object Oriented programming. I asked a question on Stack Overflow about a text adventure game I was trying to write and it was suggested that it would be better to use OOP.

I did some searching as I wanted a very simple combat system that could be used in the game. I have the basic framework from the game but I would like some help with the combat system side.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import random
import time as t

class Die:

    def __init__(self, sides = 6):
        self.sides = sides

    def roll(self):
        return random.randint(1, self.sides)

class Player:

    def __init__(self):
        self.hit_points = 10

    def take_hit(self):
        self.hit_points -= 2

class Enemy:

    def __init__(self):
        self.hit_points = 10

   def take_hit(self):
        self.hit_points -= 2

p = Player()
e = Enemy()

d = Die(6)

battle = 1
while battle != 0:

    human = d.roll() + 6
    print("Your hit score: ",human)
    enemy = d.roll() + 6
    print("Enemy hit score: ",enemy)
    if human > enemy:
        e.take_hit()
        print("Your hit points remaining: ",p.hit_points)
        print("Enemy points remaining: ", e.hit_points)
        if e.hit_points == 0:
            battle = 0
        t.sleep(2)
    elif human < enemy:
        p.take_hit()
        print("Your hit points remaining: ",p.hit_points)
        print("Enemy points remaining: ", e.hit_points)
        if p.hit_points == 0:
            battle = 0
        t.sleep(2)
```

The Die class is to simulate a six sided die, and player and enemy are used for game characters. After that the code is used to roll random number and the highest number win the round until either the player or the enemy reach zero points.

I am unsure how to use those last lines of code after the three classes and create a class from it also.

I need to be able to run a battle multiple times in the game and also store the player score with points deducted after each battle.

I really like and enjoy the use of objects and would like to become better, so any help with this is very much appreciated.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, classes/objects are nouns and functions/methods are verbs.  You should write a `fight(player, enemy)` function that takes a `Player` and an `Enemy` object as arguments, and returns the result. If you really want to stretch your OOP muscles, think about how the `Player` and `Enemy` classes are similar, and how you might use inheritance to move all the code for those similarities into one place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can re-use a class and create more instances from one template. The `Player` and `Enemy` class have a identical functionality. You can create different instances from one class simply using the `__init__` method with different arguments.

```
import random
import time as t

class Player:
    def __init__(self, hit_points, sides):
        self.hit_points = hit_points
        self.sides = sides

    def take_hit(self):
        self.hit_points -= 2

    def roll(self):
        return random.randint(1, self.sides)

p = Player(hit_points=10, sides=6)
e = Player(hit_points=8, sides=6)

battle = 1

while battle != 0:
    human = p.roll()
    print("Your hit score: ",human)
    enemy = e.roll()
    print("Enemy hit score: ",enemy)
    if human > enemy:
        e.take_hit()
        print("Your hit points remaining: ",p.hit_points)
        print("Enemy points remaining: ", e.hit_points)

    elif human < enemy:
        p.take_hit()
        print("Your hit points remaining: ",p.hit_points)
        print("Enemy points remaining: ", e.hit_points)

    t.sleep(2)

    if e.hit_points == 0 or p.hit_points == 0:
        battle = 0
```